# How to trigger destruction of viewscoped bean?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a `@ViewScoped`-annotated managedbean whose `@PostContruct`-method fetches a list from database to be displayed in a table in the view.
Now when I delete an item I want the changes to be seen in the view.
To keep this dynamic and reusable I only want to delete from database (not manually from list). So I need to destroy/recreate the bean I suppose. Now I do this by navigating to the same view. But the way I do is not reusable.
Can I just destroy the bean manually or navigate to the same view without explicitly navigating to THAT specific view (reusability)?

I am using JSF 2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already on the right track. `viewMap` is just like any other map; You can remove a `ViewScoped` bean by name. Please excuse the atrocious chaining:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("yourBean");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Though the requirements I am aware of evolved during this question, you gave a straight and correct answer to what I asked. New question will follow... :)

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found is to destroy the bean by

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().clear();
```

I am not sure if this is the way to go because it simply destroys *every* viewscoped bean. It's not that bad in this case, but doesn't feel clean.
I appreciate any thought on that or alternative solutions.

Comment: +1. The viewmap is available for you to interrogate and retrieve a specific bean by name. As a corollary, you can also `remove` a bean by name

Answer (score -1):

When you return a non null value inside a method from an action attribute the Bean gets recreated.

index.xhtml

```
...
<h:commandButton value="delete" action="bean.delete" />
...
```

Bean.class

```
...
public String delete() {
  // do operations
  return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that is just navigating to a specific view - not want I wanted (see last sentence of question).