# Cdi inject HttpSession when session is invalidated

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to implement the following behavior in my Java EE application - when user is logged and after he closes a browser or open the login page once again his session should be invalidated (so SessionScope beans are recreated).

The solution I have now:

1) Login page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

   <f:metadata>
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{logoutBean.logout}"/>
   </f:metadata>

   <f:view>
      <h:form>
         <h:outputLabel value="Login"/>
         <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.sampleAttr}"/>
         <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.authenticate()}"/>
      </h:form>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

2) Logout bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LogoutBean implements Serializable {

    public void logout() {
        FacesContext
          .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    }

}
```

3) Login bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private HttpSession session;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    }

    public String getSampleAttr() {
        return session.getAttribute("Sample") != null ? session.getAttribute("Sample").toString() :"";
    }

    public String authenticate() {
        return "default";
    }
}
```

To have a correct session after invalidation I have to assign the value of session which I get from FacesContext. When I was using session from @Inject then I received "Session already invalidated" exception in LoginBean getSampleAttr() method.

I do not understand why the session injected via Cdi still points to the old, invalidated session.

I am using CDI 1.2, JSF 2.2

Comment: Inject `Instance<HttpSession>` that should retrieve/create new session if needed

Comment: But is it a correct approach to achieve what I described so when user enter login page the existing session will be invalidated? I see it works but not sure if there is some simpler solution

Comment: The problem is how CDI gets hold of the session bean and injects it into the ViewScoped bean. It seems CDI does not proxy the HttpSession properly, and hence the proxy is still referencing the old session. By using injecting `Instance<HttpSession>`, you are forcing the provider of the `HttpSession` to ensure that it either gets an existing valid session or creates a new one

Comment: What package are you importing `@ViewScoped` from? There's an implementation of that scope that doesn't clean up after itself properly; what will then happen is even closing the browser and reopening it might result in you being handed the same bean or some other form of corrupt session state. The bean is never re-instantiated and you get a stale session.

Comment: The import is javax.faces.view.ViewScoped

Comment: Still [manually destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19504976/1530938) this viewscoped bean - to be sure it's not being re-served to you. The context definitely keeps a few around until a configured number is hit.